# Objective C: Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type id<NSObject>

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsobject

```
- (NSInteger)countForItem:(id<NSObject>)item {
    return [item[CountKey] integerValue];
}
```

This is throwing the error "Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type `id<NSObject>`

CountKey is declared as: `static NSString *CountKey = @"count";`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the object you pass (`item`) is not a dictionary. Is it a runtime warning or a compile time warning? If possible you could change the parameter to `NSDictionary` instead (preferred way). If not you can type-cast it to `NSDictionary`.

```
return [(NSDictionary*)(item)[CountKey] integerValue];
```

Comment: Thank you that pointed me in the right direction. I got past the error.